# vb.net textbox not displaying text or colors

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I have many applications that reliably display data and colors in text boxes. I copied one working program to make a new application. There are about 10 text boxes that I use for data displays. Some are working - and some are not. Here are 2 samples - the Switch code works in many programs - but here it will put the word "ON" in the box but no color, and then when the switch is off - no change to the textbox. The code seems not to care between the .AppendText or the .text = variable control. I have tried changing the properties of the text box to public but no luck. I have tried adding the .show object, and verified  the .visible attribute in the properties view. A similar problem is with the DistanceUnitsOut and the NextImageDistanceOut - I can step through the code and see the values, but the displayed data does not change! I have tried changing the definition of the display to public - no joy!

```
    SwitchStatusBox.clear
    SwitchStatusBox.AppendText(SwitchStatusIn)
    If SwitchStatusIn = "OFF" Then
        SwitchStatusBox.BackColor.Equals(Color.Red)
        SwitchStatusBox.Show()
        Switch_Is_On = False
    Else
        SwitchStatusBox.BackColor = Color.Green
        SwitchStatusBox.Show()
        Switch_Is_On = True
    End If

     If dDistance > 1.0 Then
        'show distance in Miles
        DistanceUnitsOut.Clear()
        DistanceUnitsOut.Text = "MI"
        NextImageDistanceOut.Clear()
        NextImageDistanceOut.Text = CType(dDistance, String)
    Else
        NextImageDistanceOut.Clear()
        NextImageDistanceOut.Text = CType(dDistanceFT, String)
        DistanceUnitsOut.Clear()
        DistanceUnitsOut.Text = "FT"
    End If  


    Private Sub NextImageDistanceOut_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
             NextImageDistanceOut.TextChanged
 
     End Sub

     Private Sub DistanceUnitsOut_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
                DistanceUnitsOut.TextChanged

     End Sub
```

Comment: `SwitchStatusBox.BackColor.Equals(Color.Red)`  What's this Equals thing doing for you?

Comment: Three lines below you have set the color correctly. I don't think that this code works in  other projects.

Comment: Equals is a Function that returns a Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

To see how the .Equals function works...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim a = TextBox1.BackColor.Equals(Color.Red)
    Debug.Print(a.ToString)
End Sub
```

In my test app this prints False in the Immediate window.

Comment: I think the user just meant to have `...BackColor = Color.Red`

Comment: Hi - thanks for catching the 'equals' line - Not quite sure where this crept in - the original program uses the "=" operator. I corrected that line and can step through the if statement and no change inthe color. Note that the else condition uses the correct syntax.  Still are trying to understand text not displaying - NextImageDistanceOut and DistanceUnitsOut. are examples. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that some time ago I began using <variablename_OUT> followed by the TEXT =  as in :

```
       NextImageDistanceOut.Text = CType(dDistanceFT, String)
```

what worked was:

```
      NextImageDistanceOut.Appendtext(CStr(dDistanceFT))
```

I still don't understand why the first did not work - Both require a previous

```
     NextImageDistanceOut.Clear
```